# Javascript não encontra o elemento pelo ID

Tags: javascript

Aparentemente o JavaScript não está enxergando o ID que quero mudar o seu valor.
Já verifiquei todo o código e não consegui achar o erro.

```js
  function SubMenu_EXIBE_OCULTA(menu){
    var obj=document.getElementById("menu");
      if(obj.style.display == 'block'){
        obj.style.display = 'none';
      } else {obj.style.display = 'block';}                
  }
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .Menu_Principal_ITENS {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .Menu_Principal_ITENS {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

#SubMenus_MONTAGEM {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#SubMenus_MONTAGEM a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    /* text-align: center; */
    text-align: left;
}

#SubMenus_MONTAGEM a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}


.CSS_Exibe_Oculta {display:block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>                                                         <!-- <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li> -->
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Menu_Principal_ITENS" onclick="SubMenu_EXIBE_OCULTA('SubMenus_MONTAGEM')">Clique-me</a>
    <div id="SubMenus_MONTAGEM">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>    
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade você está procurando por um id inexistente no seu `HTML` fazendo procurar por uma **string** e não a variável recebida no método.

```js
var obj=document.getElementById("menu");
```

Tente assim:

```js
 function SubMenu_EXIBE_OCULTA(menu){
    var obj=document.getElementById(menu);
      if(obj.style.display == 'block'){
        obj.style.display = 'none';
      } else {obj.style.display = 'block';}                
  }
```

Comment: Victor, tinha acabado de encontrar o erro, daí vim aqui rapidão para excluir ou responder caso alguém tivesse respondido. De qualquer forma, muitíssimo obrigado e um forte abraço.

Comment: Nao esquece de marcar a resposta pra ajudar as outras pessoas também

Comment: Como faço para marcar @Victor Laio? Procurei aqui e não encontrei...

Comment: Logo abaixo da pontuação da resposta